# Looping a query with Coldfusion

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I have a table 'scores' that contains a companyID plus some associated scores. The companyID can appear multiple times in this table. I have another table ('company') that contains the companyID and the companyName. What I want to do is query the 'company' table to get all of the companyID's and then use this result to query the 'scores' table for the scores using the results from my previous query. I need to do some calculations as well. I'm thinking I need to loop through the first result set and place the companyID value into my second query. Just not sure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I know this code won't work however it might give you a sense of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<cfquery name="companyIDs" datasource="myDB">
   Select companyID from company
</cfquery>

<cfloop>
 <cfquery name="companyScore" datasource="myDB">
 SELECT Round(sum(leadership)/Count(leadership)) as leadership,   
 Round(sum(communication)/Count(communication)) as communication, 
 Round(sum(fairness)/Count(fairness)) as fairness, 
 Round(sum(ethics)/Count(ethics)) as ethics, 
 Round(sum(competence)/Count(competence)) as competence 
 FROM scores 
 Where companyID = 'companyIDs.companyID'
 </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Than

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways to accomplish what you need, but I answered your question as you asked it.  I made some changes to your code:

```
<cfloop query='companyIDs'> // add the name of your query to the cloop
 <cfquery name="companyScore" datasource="myDB">
 SELECT Round(sum(leadership)/Count(leadership)) as leadership,   
 Round(sum(communication)/Count(communication)) as communication, 
 Round(sum(fairness)/Count(fairness)) as fairness, 
 Round(sum(ethics)/Count(ethics)) as ethics, 
 Round(sum(competence)/Count(competence)) as competence 
 FROM scores 
 Where companyID = '#companyIDs.companyID#' // add ## around your output
 </cfquery>

<cfdump var='#companyScore#'>  // dump your results

</cfloop>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested this solution and it did in fact work. That said, you, Matt and Leigh suggest that this is not the way to go. Would you agree that Matt's inner join solution is best?

Comment: I would agree that a single query would be more efficient for the processor and would be more flexible. Again, I answered the question as you asked it. If you continue to user ColdFusion, I would suggest moving toward a more complex query and simpler, more efficient code.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways you can do this, but the way below will work.

```
<cfquery name="companyIDs" datasource="myDB">
Select companyID from company
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="companyIDs">
 <cfquery name="companyScore" datasource="myDB">
 SELECT Round(sum(leadership)/Count(leadership)) as leadership,   
 Round(sum(communication)/Count(communication)) as communication, 
 Round(sum(fairness)/Count(fairness)) as fairness, 
 Round(sum(ethics)/Count(ethics)) as ethics, 
 Round(sum(competence)/Count(competence)) as competence 
 FROM scores 
 Where companyID = #companyIDs.companyID#
 </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

You can also join your two queries together, so you just have one overall query, that would be the preferred way.

```
<cfquery name="companyScore" datasource="myDB">
 SELECT companyID,
 Round(sum(leadership)/Count(leadership)) as leadership,   
 Round(sum(communication)/Count(communication)) as communication, 
 Round(sum(fairness)/Count(fairness)) as fairness, 
 Round(sum(ethics)/Count(ethics)) as ethics, 
 Round(sum(competence)/Count(competence)) as competence 
 FROM scores INNER JOIN company ON scores.companyID = company.companyID
 GROUP BY companyID
 </cfquery>
```

Comment: @Jason - Querying within a loop is rarely the right approach. Sounds like all you need is a `join`. See Matt's second example above. Though you may need to tweak it to `group` the results by `company`.

Comment: I updated my second example to be something that will likely work. Spaced off adding the company into the query.

Comment: @MattBusche - Thank you for your response. Trying to understand your code on your second example. Why am I selecting 'company' and grouping by 'company' when 'company' is the table and not a column? Thanks.

Comment: oops, should have been companyID in the SELECT

Comment: @MattBusche - Tested your second solution and it worked as well. Thank you to Leigh too.